# Best hashing technique for php mysql login?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best method for hashing user passwords in a mysql database?

Comment: I assume 'best' means 'most safe'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **Portable PHP password hashing framework**, as does Wordpress.

[Link: Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

For more information, [read this](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php
and choose a good hash function.. sha256 if you build nuclear rockets..

but using an openid would be even better:
http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/

then you don't need all those things :)

Comment: **No! Do _not_ use  use MD5!**  SHA1 is also insecure.

Comment: Yes this is why I ask, I have researched it and alot comes up saying do not this and that!

Comment: `[citation-needed]`.  It isn't.

Comment: http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Comment: about sha1: [link](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html) "[..] This attack is completely theoretical and not even remotely practical, but it demonstrates that we still have a lot to learn about hashing." you might be right.

Comment: in my opinion, collisions has nothing to do with salted hashes. Imagine you've got a string that produces the same hash. What's next?

Comment: this is an answer or question to what?

Comment: then you hope the attackee doesn't use salt :)

Comment: the link says there are collisions in sha1 seems irrelevant to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mycript](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php), and choose an appropriate hashing alghoritm (i suggest a SHA-2 family for good trade between speed / security), better with salting. 
BUT
as someone else suggested, i think it's better to use a standard frawework and don't reinvent the wheel for the thousanth time: check phpass library.

Comment: Speed is _bad_.  http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Comment: While it's an interesting article i think that -in the real world- speed is a variable, just like anything else.
It depends on how much security you really need, and how much time you are willing to let your applicatio's users wait.
Besides, in theory or for an ecommerce app, you are completely right.

Comment: With all due respect, you seem to be missing the point.  Speed is bad.  Your users will not notice the extra few milliseconds it takes to verify their credentials.  They *will* notice their accounts being hacked.

Answer (score -1):

In the first place you should be thinking not of the best hashing function but of disallowing simple passwords.

Otherwise no hashing will help.

Thus, first of all check user passwords for complexity, ask them to be at least 10 characters long, contains different case letters and numbers.

Then you have to make a hash of it, by adding some salt. users email or registration time would be okay.

```
$hashedpass = MD5($email.$pass);
```

that's all

Comment: **No! Do _not_ use  use MD5!**  Also, salts should not be alphanumeric.

Comment: Yes I have done this, all that is needed now is the actual hashing.

Comment: They don't have enough entropy, and they're more likely to appear in rainbow tables.

Comment: @SLaks a DVD per email? it's gonna be huge library

Comment: @Basic well, if you have your password strong, the hash is not a big deal.

Comment: @SLaks where you were when I asked very simple question on cracking MD5 hash? I could open it again, if you feel like to proof your words with some cracked password or two.

Comment: A purely alphanumeric salt is likely to appear in a _normal_ rainbow table.  (although an email address is somewhat less likely to)

Comment: @SLaks what is the size of string in the "normal" rainbow table? is it like 30+? If not - what is practically, not *theoretically* wrong with email salt?